# "Distributing" a sequence among other sequences

Tags: sequence, system.reactive

I have an IObservable that produces a sequence like this:

```
A1, A2, A3, A4, B1, B2, B3, B4, C1, C2, C3, C4, D1, D2, D3, D4, ...
```

I would like to have a method:

```
IObservable<T>[] Distribute(IObservable<T>, count)
```

That, when called on a IObservable, would produce other IObservables - four, in this case - so that the output of each one would be elements from a relative "position" in the original sequence (pseudo-code):

```
GetOutput(unzipped[0]) = { A1, B1, C1, D1, ... };
GetOutput(unzipped[1]) = { A2, B2, C2, D2, ... };
```

This is identical to a person dealing cards to N people (N = `count`), when you give one card for each person in sequence, then start over.

The questions are:

1. Is it possible to get that functionality with existing Rx methods?
2. If not, how could I implement it myself? I feel that using `Where` with a modulo division in the index could be acceptable, except if the answer to question 1 above is "yes"...

Answer (score 4):

When in Rx, you generally stay in `IObservable` land as long as possible. So a more natural signature would be `IObservable<IObservable<T>> Distribute(IObservabe<T> source, int count)`, which would look like this:

```
public static IObservable<IObservable<T>> Distribute<T>(this IObservable<T> source, int count)
{
    var toReturn = source.Select((t, i) => Tuple.Create(t, i))
        .GroupBy(t => t.Item2 % count)
        .Select(g => g.Select(t => t.Item1))
    return toReturn;
}
```

You can get it as an array like this:

```
public static IObservable<T>[] DistributeArray<T>(this IObservable<T> source, int count)
{
    var toReturn = new IObservable<T>[count];
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        var enclosedI = i;
        toReturn[enclosedI] = source
            .Where((t, j) => j % count == enclosedI);
    }
    return toReturn;
}
```

Comment: Beautiful, I tried the first form but the subscriptions from the generated `IObservable`s don't seem to propagate results. Take a look at https://gist.github.com/heltonbiker/2075c1ba089f695b9f9294c9bc551e66. Or perhaps there is a better way to subscribe to each created sequence that is better than `Do`.

Comment: Basically what I want are the individual IObservables, already subscribed to the source collection, so that I can in turn freely create subscriptions to each one of them.

Comment: Quick fix for the gist, is to turn the `Do` into a `Subscribe`. `Do` won't work without a `Subscribe`, at the bottom.

Comment: Given, that, there's better ways for dealing with nested observables than nested subscriptions. The easiest one would be `Merge`.

Comment: Sorry for asking again, but I still didn't understand how to apply your advice so that I can the individual IObservables assigned to variables, or in an array. I would like to subscribe to them like `sources[0].Subscribe(something)` or else `firstObservable.Subscribe(something)`. Thanks for your support!

Comment: If you're convinced you need an array, I would use `DistributeArray` from above, or something similar. However, an array is not a reactive-friendly data structure: So ask yourself if you really need that array.

Comment: Actually all I want is a way to subscribe to a given "subSource", like this: `getSubSource(sources, 0).Subscribe(Console.WriteLine)` would yield `{ 0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18}`.